# Tag helper to display a value in an input box using asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I am using asp.net core razor engine entity framework.  I am trying to get my input box to have a default value that says "Enter value here".
In my .cshtml file I have a from

```
@model login.Models.Auction
<form asp-controller="NewAuction" asp-action="New" method="post" role="form"> 
        <input asp-for="Bid" value = "Enter value here"/>
        <button type="submit">Bid</button>
</form>
```

Code for my Model.Auction.

```
    [Range(1,int.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Enter value here")]
    public int Bid { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making your property nullable on the view model:

```
[Range(1,int.MaxValue)]
[Display(Name = "Enter value here")]
public int? Bid { get; set; }
```

You could use the `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input asp-for="Bid" placeholder="Enter value here" />
```

Now assuming that the corresponding controller action didn't pass a value for this property in the view model:

```
var viewModel = new Auction
{
    Bid = null,
};
return View(viewModel);
```

you will get the desired output:

[image]

If a value is assigned to the `Bid` property on your view model then this value will be displayed in the corresponding input tag.

Answer (score 3):

i use for that a Razor extension and the html5 "@placeholder" property like that:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, new {htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Enter value here"}})
```

I think you're looking for the html attribute 'placeholder'.

Just to be clear, that's nothing special ASP.NET CORE, it's just some html-stuff